# Candle for Havdalah during Kiddush of Chag Saturday night

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, how-to, havdalah, kiddush

During the special Kiddush/Havdallah recited on a Saturday night Chag, acronym Yakneha"z, we make a bracha on the havdalah candle. Normally the Havdalah candle has to be a "torch" consisting of two or more wicks.

Is two wicks required in the Yakneha"z situation? If so, how does one achieve that given the technical difficulties including the Yom Tov prohibition on extinguishing flame.

Comment: Max, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this timely question! I hope you'll look around and find other material of interest, perhaps starting with some of our 75 other [tag:havdalah] questions. I look forward to seeing your around. Shabbat Shalom and Chag Sameyach!

Comment: Two wicks is never required for Havdala

Answer (score 3):

[Chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/611296/jewish/Holiday-Havdalah.htm) say

> For the havdalah candle we use the standard holiday candles which are
>   on the table. It is not necessary to conjoin two candles.

[Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Havdalah#Havdalah_for_Yom_Tov) says similarly:

> When Motzei Shabbat is a Yom Tov If motzei shabbat is yom tov, one may
>   use the Yom Tov candles for havdalah. It is preferable not to hold the
>   two candles together.

However one can prepare a miniature havdalah candle by melting (before Shabbos) two or three small chanukah candles together. This can be lit before kiddush/havdalah and will go out shortly after.

Comment: Some do take two candles, put them together, then separate them and put them back in their holders. Rav Moshe Feinstein allowed this if it was your family custom. Other options: wrap two birthday candles together with foil, and put them in a holder. Make the bracha, light them, and leave them till they burn out. OR, dig up a chanukah floating wick and poke another hole through the cork for a second wick, then put that in a small oil bowl.

Comment: Lighting a candle that doesn't actually provide benefit may actually be prohibited.